# Unconfirmed transaction - now can't be found!

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

24 hours unconfirmed transaction:

e52ca7c8e2c9b6bc03d35ed161afcae95cfabdf96ae6dd18d0cd8affcaaaa385

Now showing as 'no transaction can be found with that hash' on blockcypher. com

***Why is it showing as can't be found?***

I know there are a lot of similar queries, but Id appreciate if anyone is able to shed light on what is happening?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

i just checked it on Blockchain.info....its there. see pic/attachment[image: transaction]

Comment: Thanks for that, can you see if I had an appropriate fee attached to it? Am I likely to watch it sit for ever?

Comment: your welcome...and re your fee, its better than 90% of other peoples ive seen, but its still low. youre paying $15 to transact 1500....may seem high but thats the way it is right now brother

Comment: Thanks Cwick, I can see you are helping troubleshoot alot of people at the moment.

Comment: lol...excellent advice @Callerap

Comment: @cwick wrong tag, ugh.

Comment: not a big deal...anyway gl @Mickey . ;-)

Comment: Will reseeding my wallet sort this out ?

Comment: you mean re the waiting? bro theres just so many transactions that are backed up...there were over 200,000 in the mempool yesterday which is simply crazy. just be patient bro

Comment: Trying everything at the moment (except for patience ;P). okay bro, thanks again.